# Can I upload an attachment in my Stack Overflow post?

Tags: support, editor

I'm currently posting a question (about Perl script) on Stack Overflow (URL: [In Perl, how to match two consecutive Carriage Returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396278/in-perl-how-to-match-two-consecutive-carriage-returns)).

My question is about "Carriage Return"'s ASCII encoding in data file, and I want to upload a raw data file as an attachment in my post so that other viewers can reproduce my problem. It is about non-printable ASCII code, so simply pasting the raw data file in my post may ruin its effect. So now comes the question:

Can I upload a data file in Stack Overflow's post? The Stack Overflow user interface allows me to insert code sample or upload image, but I really cannot find an "upload attachment" link.

Comment: You could post a hex-dump instead.

Comment: Does it really need to be shown though? Carriage returns come in three forms; \r, \n and \r\n. You can just describe it as such. I can't imagine you're going to be asking a new question though.

Comment: @Gimby Arguably, all carriage returns are just \r, line feeds are \n. \r\n is just a combination of the two. (Although normally \n is a combination of both rather than just a line feed)

Comment: Feature request for functionality on meta.se: [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637/194720).